# how to tell cgi to stop waiting

Tags: python, cgi

Im running python on serverside and the script would be running for sometime, and I don't want to keep the user waiting.

Is there a way to print some html to CGI and tell it to stop waiting for anything more to happen. while the script is still running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGI doesn't wait for the program to exit, this is just what happens almost everytime when it waits for stdout and stderr to close.
So this is all what you should do:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.close()
sys.stderr.close()
```